# Subscript Out of Range for Looping Through Folder Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through the folder with the following code. However, I keep getting subscript out of range error. Could anyone explain what I could do to fix this issue?

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Const FileSpec As String = "*.xls"
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim iDot As Integer
    Dim FileRoot As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    Dim ArrayData() As Variant


    For y = 2009 To 2030

        ReDim Preserve ArrayData(y, 12)
        MyFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & y & "\"

        i = 1
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & FileSpec)
        Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
            iDot = InStrRev(MyFile, ".")

            If iDot = 0 Then
                FileRoot = MyFile
                FileExt = ""
            Else
                FileRoot = Left(MyFile, iDot - 1)
                FileExt = Mid(MyFile, iDot - 1)
            End If

            MyFile = Dir
            ArrayData(y, i) = FileRoot
            MsgBox ArrayData(y, i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is throwing the index out of range?  If I had to guess it is that you Dim ArrayData to `(y, 12)` but you never cap `i` and prevent it from going over 12.

Comment: ReDim Preserve ArrayData(y, 12) is throwing it out of range. Sorry, how may I cap i?

Comment: The first line inside the `For` loop is throwing the IOR?

Comment: According to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2(v=vs.80).aspx) You can only `ReDim Preserve` on the last dimension of an array, in your case, you could only change the `12` in `ReDim Preserve ArrayData(y, 12)`

Comment: Hmm, I guess the solution now is to change the order of y, 12 to 12,y. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Might I suggest that you can use `To` in your `ReDim` statement, like `ReDim Preserve ArrayData(12, 2009 To y)`. This will make the array only as big as it needs to be (instead of starting at either 0 or 1, depending on your `Option Base` setting).

Comment: Actually I have to take that back. According to MSDN, "Array Bounds. You can specify the lower and upper bound of each dimension. To do this, you include a boundslist inside the parentheses. For each dimension, the boundslist specifies the upper bound and optionally the lower bound. The lower bound is always zero, whether you specify it or not." In other words, the syntax is there, but it is ignored. No comment.

Answer (score 4):

According to this msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), You can only `ReDim Preserve` on the last dimension of an array, in your case, you could only change the `12` in `ReDim Preserve ArrayData(y, 12)`.  Changing the order of your array parameters will fix this problem.

Comment: +1 for good reference on the immediate problem. I also notice the array is dimensioned to be unnecessarily large (i.e., begins with an upper bound of 2009 when no data is ever assigned to 2008, 2007, 1955, etc.)

Comment: @DavidZemens yeah I noticed that too, but the user didn't seem to have any issues with that part of it so I let it slide.

Comment: Yep. Not causing any errors, just not very efficient, that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @TheGreatCo mentions, you can only redim the last dimension of an array.

`ReDim Preserve ArrayData(y, 12)` is throwing the error because you are trying to redim the first dimension.

Try changing to:

`ReDim Preserve ArrayData(12,y)`

And to limit `i`, change your line that says `Loop` to say:

`Loop While i <=12`

However, this still seems overkill. And although it may not cause you any errors, it is certainly inefficient.  You don't need `y` columns (2030 columns!!!) since you're never assigning anything, e.g., to ArrayData(12,1955).

You need to revise the way you're iterating over items and assign to the array more efficiently.

I would suggest:

`ReDim Preserve ArrayData(12,y-2009)`

You will then need to change:

```
ArrayData(i,y) = FileRoot
MsgBox ArrayData(i,y-2009)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what the largest value of `y` is going to be, why use the `ReDim` at all? It is extremely inefficient, since it involves relocating all your data if there is no additional (contiguous) space available, as well as copying the contents.  Instead, do

```
ArrayData(2009 To 2030, 1 To 12) As Variant
```

and don't do any redimensioning.

*This doesn't really fix the problem though*, since your value of `i` is actually the one that grows indefinitely, and your `ReDim` never considers changing the `i` dimension (it is always 12).

Depending on what you want to do, you could consider using a "collection". With a collection you can specify any string as the index; thus you could index with `CStr(y)&"-"&CStr(i)`...

Alternatively, declare the array of type Variant with initial dimensions (2,12). When you find a file root, assign the corresponding year to (1,i) and the file root to (2,i). Now you have an array that does't contain a large number of empty elements (efficient), that can be re-dimensioned (along the second dimension), and that captures all the data of the original. In effect you have created your own "sparse array".

One more aside:

Contrary to what I mentioned in the comments above, when I tried to use the `To` construct iin Excel VBA and then inspected the variable, it seemed to do exactly what you would expect - but it wasn't possible to redim an array once it had been declared with upper and lower bounds.